# AngularJS Filter: Checkbox active by default based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am working on a prototype that uses AngularJS to filter JSON data. A working sandbox is here:

https://codepen.io/ixdarchitects/pen/BaypxrW

I need your help to solve 2 Problems:

1. How to use the "Check All" and "Uncheck All" button to activate/deactivate all of the checkbox filters?
2. Filter by default: How to make the webpage only show gray bird when the page is initialized?

Thank you

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yfNm.png)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="petSelector" ng-controller="PetCtrl" class="wrapper">
<h1>Pet Picker!</h1>
<hr>
<h3>Problems to solve:</h3>
<ol>
<li>How to use the "Check All" and "Uncheck All" button to activate/deactivate all of the checkbox filters?</li>
<li>Filter by default: How to make the webpage only show gray bird when the page is initialized?</li>
</ol>

<hr>
<div class="attr" ng-repeat="(prop, ignoredValue) in pets[0].FilterAttributes" ng-init="filter[prop]={}" ng-class="prop">
<b>{{prop}}:</b><br />
<span class="checkbox" ng-repeat="opt in getOptionsFor(prop)">
  <label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="filter[prop][opt]" />&nbsp;{{opt}}</label>
</span>
</div>

<button ng-click="checkAll()" style="margin-right: 10px">Check all</button>
<button ng-click="uncheckAll()" style="margin-right: 10px">Uncheck all</button>

<div class="results">Number of results: {{filtered.length}}</div>
<div class="pet" ng-repeat="p in filtered=(pets | filter:filterByProp | orderBy:order)">
<img ng-src="{{p.img}}">
<p>{{p.name}}</p>
</div>
<div ng-if="filtered.length == 0">Sorry, nothing matches your selection</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var petSelector = angular.module("petSelector", []);

petSelector.controller("PetCtrl", [
 "$scope",
  function($scope) {
$scope.pets = [
  {
    name: "Finch",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "bird", size: "x-small", color: "red" },
    img:
      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7c/Fringilla_coelebs_chaffinch_male_edit2.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Cockatiel",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "bird", size: "small", color: "yellow" },
    img: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Captive.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "African Gray Parrot",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "bird", size: "large", color: "gray" },
    img:
      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Psittacus_erithacus_-perching_on_tray-8d.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Macaw",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "bird", size: "x-large", color: "blue" },
    img:
      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/00/Macaw.blueyellow.arp.750pix.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Shih Tzu",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "dog", size: "x-small", color: "multi" },
    img: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Shih-Tzu.JPG"
  },
  {
    name: "Border Collie",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "dog", size: "small", color: "multi" },
    img:
      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Border_Collie_liver_portrait.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "American Staffordshire Terrier",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "dog", size: "large", color: "gray" },
    img: "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/AmStaff2.jpg"
  },
  {
    name: "Bullmastiff",
    FilterAttributes: { species: "dog", size: "x-large", color: "brown" },
    img:
      "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9e/Bullmastiff_Junghund_1_Jahr.jpg"
  }
];

$scope.filter = {};

$scope.getOptionsFor = function(propName) {
  return ($scope.pets || [])
    .map(function(p) {
      return p.FilterAttributes[propName];
    })
    .filter(function(p, idx, arr) {
      return arr.indexOf(p) === idx;
    });
};

$scope.filterByProp = function(pets) {
  var matchesAND = true;
  for (var prop in $scope.filter) {
    if (noSubFilter($scope.filter[prop])) continue;
    if (!$scope.filter[prop][pets.FilterAttributes[prop]]) {
      matchesAND = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return matchesAND;
};

function noSubFilter(subFilterObj) {
  for (var key in subFilterObj) {
    if (subFilterObj[key]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

}
]);
```

CSS

```
    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica', arial, sans-sarif;
  color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
}

b {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 40px;
  background: #00a5bb;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.attr {
  width: 32%;
  margin: 0 .5%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
}

.results {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px 0 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.pet {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.pet img {
  max-width: 85%;
  max-height: 200px;
}
.pet.ng-enter, .pet.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
.pet .ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.pet.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  height: auto;
}
.pet.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see your version of checkAll, uncheckAll methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve what you are asking for adding the following two $scope functions.

`$scope.checkAll` iterates all `pets` `FilteredAttributes` and their values and set them at true into `$scopeFilter`.

$scope.uncheckAll simply reset the `$scopeFilter` object.

For the default filter, I removed `ng-init="filter[prop]={}"` to initiliaze `$scopeFilter` in the .js file as follows :

```
$scope.filter = {species : {bird : true} , color : {gray: true}};
```

```js
$scope.checkAll = function(){
    const result = {};
    $scope.pets.map(pet => pet.FilterAttributes)
      .forEach( attribute => Object.keys(attribute)
               .forEach( prop => {
                   if(result[prop]){
                       result[prop][attribute[prop]] = true
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       result[prop] = {};
                       result[prop][attribute[prop]] = true
                   }
               })
      );
    $scope.filter = result;
};


$scope.uncheckAll = function(){
   $scope.filter = {}
};
```

You can find the solution here https://codepen.io/dmnized/pen/povRQOE?editors=1010

Comment: Could you help to take a look at this challenge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461678/angularjs-filter-filter-multiple-attributes-object-using-checkbox